# UITableView not reversing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5

I'm working on information retrieval where in the latest information in on top of UITableView. The code goes like this.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    LoanModel* loan = _feed.products[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" ];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[loan name]];
    NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];    
    NSMutableArray *reversed = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myWords count]];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myWords reverseObjectEnumerator];

    for (id element in enumerator) { 
        [reversed addObject:element];
    }

    NSMutableString *reverseString = [reversed componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    cell.textLabel.text = reverseString;

    return cell;
}
```

I'm getting the `JSON` object which contain two fields cid and name respectively. I'm showing only the name is tableview. But I want to show it in reverse i,e last update should show at first. But above code showing the content in reverse. IF "hello" is the content, then it shows "olleh". Please suggest me how to get the `UITableView` in reverse list. I'm a newbie to iOS.

Comment: What the Value of myString ?

Comment: You mean you wanna show your tableview's cell like o,l,l,e,h(reverse) order.?

Comment: As per your code, you are fetching feed in this method only not any other right?

Comment: I'm retrieving a json object which contain two fields cid and name. I just want to show the value in names in reverse order.

Comment: @cultor: Yes. the "loan" has the two fields cid and name. I managed to show the list in right order. But showing in reverse order is giving problem.

Comment: @user2364594 just,print your `myString` and see how does it looks like. There is a problem with the actual string that is coming in `[loan name]`

Comment: You should try to include something like displayOrder or something and sort based on it. Instead off relying the order from the source.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the reversed order of cells / objects they represent, you have to change

```
LoanModel* loan = _feed.products[indexPath.row];
```

to

```
LoanModel* loan = _feed.products[_feed.products.count - 1 - indexPath.row];
```

assuming that `_feed.products` is an `NSArray`.

Comment: This is a better solution than physically reversing the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

The array you are using to display the the data in tableView, you'll need to reverse that and then display the data in tableView

`NSArray* reversed = [[myArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];`

you can use this to make your array objects order in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSArray* reversedArray = [[myWords reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```